# How do I begin beta testing?

Tags: testing, beta

I have a project that I would like to start beta testing soon, it is a PHP/MySQL site for programmers. I have beta tested sites before however it was always in-house, and I have never done betas that could/should be seen by someone other then those associated with the project.

How should I go about starting the beta, and what problems, aside from those the beta is supposed to expose, should I be prepared for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, accept the fact that problems with your app (code, usability, etc.) will be discovered.

Then, make sure you have a clear way for users to communicate with you (form mail, email, uservoice, etc.). The easier you make this the better. For example, there is a uservoice link on every page of SO.

One philosophy I strongly believe in: if it's confusing to your users, it's broken. Be willing to change your app (no matter how "beautiful" the design may be) if your users are confused or not liking it.  This doesn't mean you have to cave on your decisions, just that you need to consider revisions to improve the user experience.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Jeff's post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001159.html) on it, I think he has recent experience ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, problems related to the people?  Are you referring to usability problems?

Also, if you are doing a beta,it means you already did everything you know (in my opinion). One of the goals of a beta is to show you what you didn't knew, besides unexpected code problems, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Beta testing is a part of acceptance testing.
This type of testing will ensure the customer about the functionality and quality of the product.
Beta testing is done on customers end in an uncontrolled environment.
In beta testing customer driven test cases are written and he can enter whatever he wants to enter.
Here developer don't have any control over the testing approach.